# How does ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem work with a grouped list?

Tags: .net, wpf, listbox

I have a ListBox which until recently was displaying a flat list of items. I was able to use myList.ItemContainerGenerator.ConainerFromItem(thing) to retrieve the ListBoxItem hosting "thing" in the list.

This week I've modified the ListBox slightly in that the CollectionViewSource that it binds to for its items has grouping enabled. Now the items within the ListBox are grouped underneath nice headers.

However, since doing this, ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem has stopped working - it returns null even for items I know are in the ListBox. Heck - ContainerFromIndex(0) is returning null even when the ListBox is populated with many items!

How do I retrieve a ListBoxItem from a ListBox that's displaying grouped items?

Edit: Here's the XAML and code-behind for a trimmed-down example. This raises a NullReferenceException because ContainerFromIndex(1) is returning null even though there are four items in the list.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:scm="clr-namespace:System.ComponentModel;assembly=WindowsBase"
    Title="Window1">

    <Window.Resources>
        <XmlDataProvider x:Key="myTasks" XPath="Tasks/Task">
            <x:XData>
                <Tasks xmlns="">
                    <Task Name="Groceries" Type="Home"/>
                    <Task Name="Cleaning" Type="Home"/>
                    <Task Name="Coding" Type="Work"/>
                    <Task Name="Meetings" Type="Work"/>
                </Tasks>
            </x:XData>
        </XmlDataProvider>

        <CollectionViewSource x:Key="mySortedTasks" Source="{StaticResource myTasks}">
            <CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="@Type" />
                <scm:SortDescription PropertyName="@Name" />
            </CollectionViewSource.SortDescriptions>

            <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
                <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="@Type" />
            </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
        </CollectionViewSource>
    </Window.Resources>

    <ListBox 
        x:Name="listBox1" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource mySortedTasks}}" 
        DisplayMemberPath="@Name"
        >
        <ListBox.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle>
                <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
            </GroupStyle>
        </ListBox.GroupStyle>
    </ListBox>
</Window>
```

CS:

```
public Window1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
}

void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;

        var i = listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) as ListBoxItem;

        // select and keyboard-focus the second item
        i.IsSelected = true;
        i.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with the container? Can you possible exapnd on what the previous code did that actually worked? There are a few ways to get the container... it just depends on what you want to do with it?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You **have** to listen and react to the `ItemsGenerator.StatusChanged` Event and wait until the ItemContainers are generated before you can access them with ContainerFromElement.

---

Searching further, I've found [a thread in the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpf/thread/8be8307b-83dd-4658-971d-22d47a34dfb6/) from someone who has the same problem. This seems to be a bug in WPF, when one has a GroupStyle set. The solution is to punt the access of the ItemGenerator after the rendering process. Below is the code for your question. I tried this, and it works:

```
    void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.Status
            == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged
                -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Input,
                new Action(DelayedAction));
        }
    }

    void DelayedAction()
    {
        var i = listBox1.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(1) as ListBoxItem;

        // select and keyboard-focus the second item
        i.IsSelected = true;
        i.Focus();
    }
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm doing that. I'll update the question early next week with some code.

Comment: Just tried that out myself. Helps me out on something I had trouble with this weekend.

Comment: Awesome - thanks David. I've not had a chance to test this yet but I'll accept this as "the" answer for now.

Comment: You should be using System.Action instead of VoidDelegate.

Comment: @justin: I've removed the VoidDelegate

Comment: I don't believe this problem is limited to the case where there is a GroupStyle set.  See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363777

Comment: @Cheeso: that may be the case. I only explored this specific use case.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the answer David, it helped solve a similar problem. One change that I would like to point out was to first check if the `ItemContainerGenerator` is ready and if so dispatch the action instead of waiting for the status to change. This solves a bug where it wouldn't work the first time. 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7366961/listbox-scrollintoview-when-using-collectionviewsource-with-groupdescriptions-i/7414200#7414200

Comment: Note for others, in my case I'm wanting to reference the ListBoxItem after each item is added but the status change event could be firing for a previous added item with status set to ContainersGenerated. So instead I'm checking to see if ContainerFromIndex returns null or not before proceeding. Thanks for your help David.

Comment: An update on this one (you might like to include this comment in your answer, David).

I had another grouped ListBox that was experiencing this problem, and I only got it to work after removing the "unsubscribe from event" line in the code above. The event was getting fired multiple times even after the containers were first generated.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 2):

If the above code doesn't work for you, give this a try

```
public class ListBoxExtenders : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AutoScrollToCurrentItemProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("AutoScrollToCurrentItem", typeof(bool), typeof(ListBoxExtenders), new UIPropertyMetadata(default(bool), OnAutoScrollToCurrentItemChanged));

    public static bool GetAutoScrollToCurrentItem(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(AutoScrollToSelectedItemProperty);
    }

    public static void SetAutoScrollToCurrentItem(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(AutoScrollToSelectedItemProperty, value);
    }

    public static void OnAutoScrollToCurrentItemChanged(DependencyObject s, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var listBox = s as ListBox;
        if (listBox != null)
        {
            var listBoxItems = listBox.Items;
            if (listBoxItems != null)
            {
                var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;

                var autoScrollToCurrentItemWorker = new EventHandler((s1, e2) => OnAutoScrollToCurrentItem(listBox, listBox.Items.CurrentPosition));

                if (newValue)
                    listBoxItems.CurrentChanged += autoScrollToCurrentItemWorker;
                else
                    listBoxItems.CurrentChanged -= autoScrollToCurrentItemWorker;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void OnAutoScrollToCurrentItem(ListBox listBox, int index)
    {
        if (listBox != null && listBox.Items != null && listBox.Items.Count > index && index >= 0)
            listBox.ScrollIntoView(listBox.Items[index]);
    }

}
```

Usage in XAML

```
<ListBox IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" extenders:ListBoxExtenders.AutoScrollToCurrentItem="True" ..../>
```

Comment: This fixed the issue for me. Thanks!  Now to understand why...  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Try parsing the VisualTree up from the 'thing' until you reach a ListBoxItem type

Comment: Jobi - "thing" in this case isn't a visual element - it's an instance of a business object. Part of an IList<Thing> that the ListBox's ItemsSource is bound to. Can I do what you're describing under that scenario?

Comment: Yeah got you. thanks for the clarification. From which part of the code behind you are trying to do this? any DataTemplate click or in some other event handler?

Comment: When the page (it's a Navigation-style application) loads, I want to set keyboard focus to a specific element. So in the Loaded event handler.

Comment: Actually that's not quite true. I'm doing it in the ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged event handler on the ListBox, which I hooked up in the Loaded event.