# WPF Bind DataTable to repeated user controls

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I'm in the process of teaching myself WPF, and I have run into a small issue that I can't find the answer to.

My test app allows image files to be dropped into a StackPanel.  Once an image is dropped, a new user control is added to the stack, and displays some meta-data about the file.  All is working correctly, and I can iterate through the child controls to retrieve the values.

What I'd prefer to be able to do is allow the user to persist this data to a file, so they can suspend working on the data.  The obvious way for me to do this is to store the data in a DataTable and serialise/deserialise it to xml.  However, I don't know how to drive the collection of user controls from a DataTable or DataSet object - in fact, I don't even know if this is the right way to go about it in a WPF app.  I am more than willing to admit my ignorance here and take better suggestions if there are any.

Summary of the app logic.

1) File is dropped (from Win explorer) onto a StackPanel
2) File triggers creation of a new user control, which is added to the StackPanel
3) Data is populated in the user control
4) Processing data involves iterating through the control collection.

What I'd like

1) File is dropped (from Win explorer) onto a StackPanel
2) File data is inserted into some persistable object (data table?)
3) updated data table drives the generation of the user control to be added to the displayed collection.
4) save / load functionality persists the data for re-use later.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're on the right track with the second approach, what you need to look at is the ItemsControl - that's a thing which can have items added to it. It's the base for ListBox etc, and you can [template it to work as you require](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.groupstyle.aspx). Then there's the DataTemplate which handles which controls are displayed and data binding to those controls when an item is added to the underlying data structure. There are quite a few examples around on the net, try [Dr WPF](http://www.drwpf.com/blog/Home/tabid/36/EntryID/24/Default.aspx).

In order to make everything work the underlying data structure must support change notification. As everything happens automagically, once the Xaml is setup, you can find yourself in an odd situation. You've added data to a data structure, which in turn has caused controls and data to appear in your ItemsControl. How do you link the data items and their visual controls. The answer is to use some built in static methods [ItemFromContainer](http://blog.nostatic.org/2007/12/wpf-listview-getting-clicked-item.html) which links from the graphic to your underlying data item, useful to handle click events, and [ContainerFromItem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165424/how-does-itemcontainergeneratorcontainerfromitem-work-with-a-grouped-list) which does the reverse.