# How to fix ComboBox index issue in C#

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, wpf-controls

I wrote a WPF application in which my `ComboBox.Items.IndexOf(ItemName);` giving -1 even though Item is present in the `ComboBox` `items` list. Can anybody please help me to get the solution.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please post a short, simple, and concise code example? http://sscce.org/

Comment: IndexOf will not work on ItemName but on Item object itself.

Can you show us databinging code or at least collection you have bind your combobox to?

Comment: @Turtleneck, in WPF items controls (such as `ComboBox`), the `Items.IndexOf()` isnt a search by name. Also `ComboBox.Items` are not **always** `ComboboxItems` they can be the individual items of a collection bound to the combobox. To search a comboboxItem you will have to refer the concept of `ItemsContainer`... see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/165424/how-does-itemcontainergenerator-containerfromitem-work-with-a-grouped-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.IndexOf` is looking for the object in the items collection rather than looking for it by name (which is what you are indicating that you want to do). You should use `ComboBox.FindStringExact("ItemName")` to get what you require.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe that this is how you set the list to blank, hence the " - " before the 1, indicating that it's below the 0 threshold which items begin to be indexed.