# Binding Errors in DataTemplated ListBoxItems

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox, datatemplate

Currently i have a user control which contains a listbox of other visual element user controls; which (for this special case) have been data templated.

```
<Grid>
    <ListBox ItemSource="{Binding Path=UserControlCollection}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                      <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
                      <Button/>
                  </StackPanel>
             </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
</Grid>
```

The issue is that i have [This Issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/160391/listbox-with-grid-as-itemspaneltemplate-produces-weird-binding-errors) And because of the data template, i can't seem to find a way to correct the styling issue.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found by overriding the `ListBoxItem`'s horizontalcontentalignment and verticalcontentalignment i was able to correct the issue.

```
 <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
     <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
         <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
         <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
     </Style>
 </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
```

I also found changing to a listview helpful but did have issues of its own.